# (jetpack compose) androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack, android-jetpack-compose

I have an BaseUi class for my custom views and my activities extends from it. 
whe i using `Root` function , application crashed.

**BaseUi.kt**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
open class BaseUi : AppCompatActivity() {

@Composable
fun RtlView(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(
        LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Rtl,
        content = content
    )
}

@Composable
fun LtrView(content: @Composable () -> Unit) {
    CompositionLocalProvider(LocalLayoutDirection provides LayoutDirection.Ltr) {
        content()
    }
}

@Composable
fun Root(
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    KasbTheme {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .background(LightPageBackground)
                .padding(Dimen.pagePadding)
        ){
            content()
        }
    }
}
}
```

**SplashActivity.kt**

```
@ExperimentalAnimationApi
class SplashActivity : BaseActivity() {

val viewModel = SplashActivityViewModel()

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContent {
        InitUI()
    }
}

@ExperimentalAnimationApi
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun InitUI() {
    Root {
        RtlView {
            Box(Modifier.fillMaxSize()) {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(id = R.drawable.logo),
                    contentDescription = "",
                    modifier = Modifier.size(200.dp).align(Alignment.Center)
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

**Runtime error**

```
com.kasb.android E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.kasb.android, PID: 22387
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl cannot be cast to kotlin.jvm.functions.Function0
        at com.kasb.android.ui.activity.SplashActivity.InitUI(SplashActivity.kt:76)
        at com.kasb.android.ui.activity.SplashActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(SplashActivity.kt:30)
        at com.kasb.android.ui.activity.SplashActivity$onCreate$1.invoke(SplashActivity.kt:29)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:107)
        at androidx.compose.runtime.internal.ComposableLambdaImpl.invoke(ComposableLambda.jvm.kt:34)
        at androidx.compose.ui.platform.ComposeView.Content(ComposeView.android.kt:384)
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Answer (score 5):

not a permanent fix, but clean project gets rid of the error for one compile. Don't know why it's happening though.

Comment: did you find a workarround to avoid the cleaning of the project?

Comment: I don't think so, we moved on to a new project so I don't remember, but it doesn't happen in our new project at all. So maybe update all libraries and the IDE.

Answer (score 1):

I had same error, and problem was caused that I was calling function form subtype of the class where it was defined

```
    BaseActivity{
     fun displayAlertDialog(content: @Composable() () -> Unit) {
        bottomDialog.show(supportFragmentManager, "bottom-dialog")
        bottomDialog.setContent(content)
    }
            @Composable
            fun Screen(
                activity: BaseActivity,
            ) {
            activity.displayAlertDialog{} 
            }
        
        // works fine
        //if activity is subtype of BaseActivity it throws that error
```

Comment: Does this mean comose doesn't work well with inheritance? I've been experiencing this and don't know how to solve it if the inheritance is required.

Comment: I have the same issue where inheritance is causing a problem. But in my case, it was two levels up. Basically, a Grandfather class (GrandFather -> Father -> Child) had a function that I could not access in the child class. If the function was in the Father class, it worked fine. Extension functions work well, though, in this case, so I move my functions to be extension functions with composable blocks as parameters.

Answer (score 1):

simple way, you just put the composable function into Class delegate,

```
writer.writeLine(${binding}.${handleMethod}(${IssueFixClass::class.simpleName}.${IssueFixClass.Delegate::makeClass.name}(contentListBlock$timestamp)))
```

result like this

```
binding.handleUIGroupCreator( IssueFixClass.makeClass(content64966723696806))
```

my kmm androidMain

```
actual class IssueFixClass private actual constructor(val content:@Composable @UiComposable ()->Unit){
    @Composable
    @UiComposable
    actual fun invoke(){
        content.invoke()
    }
    actual companion object Delegate{
        actual fun makeClass(content: @Composable @UiComposable () -> Unit):IssueFixClass{
          return  IssueFixClass(content)
        }
    }
}
```